# Debianize upstream `zip`-file with `gbp` and `pristine-tar`

Tags: git, debian, packaging, debhelper

[The manual of gbp](http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.import.html#GBP.IMPORT.FROMSCRATCH) tells following:

> First, create an empty repository:
>
> ```
> mkdir package-0.1
> cd package-0.1
> git init
> ```
>
> Then, you import the upstream sources, branch off the upstream-branch branch and add the Debian files (e.g. via dh_make):
>
> ```
> gbp import-orig -u 0.1 ../package-0.1.tar.gz
> dh_make
> ```
>
> That's it, you're done.

But this fails with a `zip` because there is no `.orig.tar.gz`.  Invoking `dh_make --createorig` creates an `.orig.tar.gz`, but this then includes the `.git/` subdirectory, so it is invalid.

Also the `pristine-tar` branch is missing this way and `pristine-tar commit` does not know how to handle `zip` files.

How do I start a Debian package if the upstream only provides a `zip`-file?  How to handle `pristine-tar` in that case?

Answer (score 4):

(this here still is a bit untested)

For the benefit of the reader, this is what I came up with.  I am not sure that this is BCP, but it works.  On Linux and probably CygWin, too.

My current workflow to create a Debian repository from scratch with `gbp` is:

## Import upstream

Upstream usually is an `.orig.tar.gz`, but following works with `ZIP` too.  For all supported archive types, please see `man gbp-import-orig`.

### Set some variables

This variables are used, that you can use copy and paste with the following lines of the recipe.

```
PACKAGENAME=mypackagename
UPSTREAMVERSION=0.1.2.3-up4
UPSTREAMARCHIVE=../upstreampackage-$UPSTREAMVERSION.zip

# Following should start/end with a number and only contain
# numbers, lowercase letters and single dots (.)
MYDIST=stable
MYBASEVERSION=0example.com1

TEMPLATEGIT=https://github.com/hilbig/templates.git
TEMPLATEBRANCH=gbp
```

### Create the git repo

```
git init $PACKAGENAME
cd $PACKAGENAME
```

Initialize the repo

```
git commit --allow-empty -m empty
git branch upstream
git fetch $TEMPLATEGIT $TEMPLATEBRANCH
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

### First import of upstream

```
echo $PACKAGENAME | fakeroot gbp import-orig --upstream-version=$UPSTREAMVERSION $UPSTREAMARCHIVE
```

### Create `debian/`

```
dh_make --indep -a -p ${PACKAGENAME}_$UPSTREAMVERSION
git add debian
git commit -m "dh_make --indep -a -p  ${PACKAGENAME}_$UPSTREAMVERSION"
```

### Edit files in `debian/`

Now change all files in `debian/` to your needs and deleted unwanted files (hint: `rm -f *.ex`).  Sorry, I found no way to automate this properly.  Do not alter files outside of `debian/` as those are handled using quilt/patchqueues (AKA `debian/patches/`) later on.  Be sure to edit `debian/changelog`:

- Change `unstable` (in the first line) to the value of `$MYDIST`.  (It does not hurt if you don't.)
- Change the text `* Initial release (Closes: #nnnn) ...` to something better like `debianized upstream XXX into package YYY`.
- If the last line is wrong, you probably forgot to set your usual `git config` settings (which is kept in `~/.gitconfig`).  Do it now:
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
  git config --global user.email you@example.com

If everything is set up in `debian/`, then commit it:

```
git add -A debian
# Use "git status" to see, that only file in "debian/" are changed
git commit -m 'edited directory debian/'
```

### Setup `gbp dch`

> Following is rubbish.  I still try to figure out how do do it properly, because the needed tags are not created automatically as I thought they should.

<s>If you want to use `gbp dch --auto` (which is recommended) this needs a properly set `git tag`.  As you can change the format of those tags in `debian/gbp.conf` it is recommended to create the first tag using `gbp dch --since` (you can create it manually if you like, but we want to automate, right?) like this:</s>

```
gbp dch --commit -D "$MYRELEASE" -N "`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 upstream | sort | head -1 | sed s/^[^0-9]*//`-$MYBASEVERSION" --since HEAD^
vim debian/changelog
git commit --amend debian/changelog
```

### Push it to your git-server

When pushing to your `git` server, be sure always to include the tags:

```
git push origin --tags
```

Those (uncommented) tags are used for various reference/tracking purpose.

## Explained

- The `git fetch` populates `FETCH_HEAD` with branch `$TEMPLATEBRANCH` from the `git` repo `$TEMPLATEGIT`, so it can be merged easily.
  This should create `debian/gbp.conf` with your favorite settings which include `pristine-tar` being enabled.
- `echo $PACKAGENAME | fakeroot gbp ...` does 2 things:

  - `gbp` will ask for the package name.  Unfortunately there is no commandline option for this.  Hence it is `echo`ed into it to be able to run it batch-like.
  - `fakeroot` fixes a glitch where option `pristine-tar` (which can be missing from the commandline if set in `gbp.conf`) will create a `.tar` file with your user instead of `root:root`.
- `dh_make` needs `-a` to populate the `debian/` directory, as there already is one which only contains `gbp.conf`.
- If there is no `debian/gbp.conf` when you first call `gbp`, then you need to add the option `pristine-tar` to `gbp import-orig`.
  Without it looks like it works, but there will be no usable `.orig.tar.gz` (which can be named `.bz2` or `.xz`, too).
  `gbp` is the only tool recognizing `.zip`-files, so you will get into some trouble if you forget this.
  Unfortunately the option's name differs between versions of `gbp` (either `--git-pristine-tar` or `--pristine-tar`), so it is better to have it in `gbp.conf`.

Notes:

- In future there will be `gbp init` to improve these steps, however my current variant of `gbp` does not include this yet.
- File `debian/gbp.conf` shall look like following.  Above it is supposed to be merged via `git merge FETCH_HEAD` from branch `$TEMPLATEBRANCH` of repo `$TEMPLATEGIT`.
  Perhaps create your own `git` template repository for this, see also `https://github.com/hilbix/templates/tree/gbp`:

`debian/gbp.conf`:

```
[DEFAULT]
pristine-tar = True
debian-branch = master
debian-tag = v%(version)s

[dch]
full = True
git-author = True

[pq]
patch-num-format = PATCH-%04d-

[import-orig]
merge-mode = replace
```

## Follow the usual workflow

Afterwards you can follow the usual `gbp` workflow, so all other typical recipes on the web on how to change a Debian package can be used.

Here is, how I do it (sort of).

### Build the package

Simple packages are easy.  However some packages need more than that, like being compiled for 64bit, with sources, and parts are even for arch `all`.  Also the `.orig.tar.gz` is missing after you cloned everything.  Hence you need quite a trainload of options to handle that all properly.

Following assumes that you want to create for Intel platform and (optionally) providing 32 bit for older systems:

```
gbp buildpackage --dist="$MYDIST" --git-builder=sbuild --arch=amd64 --arch-all --source --force-orig-source
gbp buildpackage --dist="$MYDIST" --git-builder=sbuild --arch=i386
```

Notes:

- `--git-builder=sbuild` is an example.  If you have trouble, just leave this away.  Some newer `gbp` also renamed this option.
- Build often leaves some aritfacts.  Do a cleanup with (**Caution!**  This will unconditionally remove all uncommited edits if there are any!):

  git reset --hard

### Use quilt format (patchqueues) to alter upstream

If you need to change things outside of `debian/`, this is the way to go:

```
gbp pq import
# now edit everything here
# if you are happy with it:
gbp pq export
```

You definitively want to use patchqueues, because you do not want to touch the upstream version which was merged into `master`.  This way you do not accidentally loose all of your changes when a new upstream comes along, and moreover, new upstreams will merge more cleanly.

Please note that `gbp buildpackage` knows about patchqueues.  They will be applied automatically, so you do not need to apply them yourself.

### Create a new release

Before creating a new release, you perhaps want to cleanup your `git` commit log.  Do this with:

```
git rebase -i COMMIT
```

`COMMIT` stands for the first commit you are happy with.  `git rebase` is a very powerful tool, but beware: Do not try to rebase beyond `merge`-Commits, as those then will be wiped out.  If your `git` commit history is clean (see `git log`), create the next `debian/changelog`:

```
gbp dch --commit -D $MYDIST
```

Leave away `--commit` to do the commit yourself, or alter the options of this as it suits you.

### Import a new upstream

Set the parameters for the new upstream and then do:

```
echo $PACKAGENAME | fakeroot gbp import-orig --upstream-version=$UPSTREAMVERSION $UPSTREAMARCHIVE
```

Please note that this fails if your repo is not clean. (`git status --porcelain` does not output anything).

Then create a new `debian/changlog` entry for this:

```
gbp dch --commit -D "$MYDIST" -N "`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 upstream | sort | head -1 | sed s/^[^0-9]*//)-$MYBASEVERSION"
```